From one, to another, to another, to another and to another
The answer to this puzzle is a word. No knowledge other than trivial is needed.



Made an edit guys. Since it's been unsolved for quite some time now I edited the puzzle to what I initially planned it to look like.

That wasn’t difficult to work out its just what’s come below it that’s difficult and trying to find a word out of all of it…

@PDT Yeah, but I also think it looks more complete now

Interesting use of 'quite some time'...! Only 13 hours - you've clearly got used to some fast solves of late! :)

@Stiv Yup, definitely so. I often expect my puzzles to be solved within a short period of time because they often do (depending on the type of puzzle ofc). This one requires different type of thinking though, so I'm not very surprised it hasn't been solved yet.

FYI I'm pretty positive I managed to deduce the intended answer word quite early on. I just need to work out if there's some kind of systematic logical pattern I'm missing since as it would currently stand my answer would look to have involved a bit of guesswork for the final extraction...

@Stiv Okay, yeah there's definitely a systematic logical pattern involved. If you've managed to work out how to interpret the figures correctly then it will lead you to the correct answer (without guesswork).

The word is ...

 ... VIEWPOINT.

It is clear ...

 ... that we are looking at the same tower of cubes from different viewpoints. The views are numbered: The front, top, left side, right side and rear views have the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 respectively.

 The missing view is the top view.

What do we know about the cubes?

 Let's look at the top cube first. We know the letters from views 1, 3, 4 nd 5. We don't know the letters on the top and bottom sides.

 We can know only two letters from the orange cubes and at most two letters from the yellow cubes.

 In particular, we know this about the cubes whose top faces are visible:

U.WXY. red
V.X... O..R.. ...KL. orange
H.J... M..... S..V.. ...Q.. ...GH. yellow

 The letters are numbered according to the given enumeration. The gaps in the red cube are easily filled with a V and a Z to form a stretch of consecutive letters, but the other cubes can be filled in in this manner, too:

UVWXYZ red
VWXYZA OPQRST HIJKLM orange
HIJKLM MNOPQR STUVWX NOPQRS DEFGHI yellow

 (Unfortunately, only the cubes that are relevant for the solution have this property, which I find unfortunate. For example, there' a cube with two F's at the edge between the left and read sides.)

This leads to ...

 ... the following arrangement:

 Seen from the top, and read from back to front and from left to right, the letters spell VIEWPOINT.


This was exactly my conclusion too - especially that the lower 'unused' cubes didn't seem to share this property. But I was hesitant in posting my methods as it wasn't clear to me why (e.g.) the yellow cube with G and H should lead to E while the one with S and V should lead to T. However, I now see I wasn't comparing 'like with like' and should instead have been comparing it to the orange cube with K and L, which is in the same orientation. Thanks for explaining it so well :)

Thanks. I'm not so sure I described it well, but the picture helps, I guess. I saw what was going on only after I wrote a little program to raw the tower, which used global enumeraions and defined the letters by the given strings ("H.J..."), but because the pattern only applies to the relevant cubes (a mistake, in my opinion), it took me a while. (Also, after having looked at yesterday's stolen paper puzzle, I briefly thought "Oh, so it's hijabi again, is it?") :)

Great job! You got it, even though I clearly made mistakes. I might make an edit later and correct that.., anyways well done!

Thanks, @Prim3numbah. I've said above that in not using the pattern on all cubes is a mistake, but that's just my opinion. It certainly held me up, but the puzzle works as is, so it's not a clear mistake. I can even see how not using the pattern consistently can be an effective red herring. And I liked the main feature of the puzzle.

Glad you enjoyed the overall idea. Yes, but I agree it was a mistake from my side neglecting the pattern in the bottom and second bottom "layer" of the figure. I honestly just made a quick wrong first assumption thinking they don't matter anyways. Didn't even think about it before you pointed it out. My focus was solely on getting the top view to spell the correct word. I double checked couple of times making sure all the letters, from different viewpoints, were placed correctly.

Oh in the third layer too :D
